# Очистка памяти Android устройства

Tags: android, память

столкнулся с такой проблемой, что память на Android устройстве переполнена, однако если изначально я мог установить парочку приложений и пользоваться 10 гб свободной памяти, то сейчас удалив даже все медиафайлы и оставив часть приложений у меня остается 2гб, при том 18 гб уходит на "Прочее". Попытался через пк посмотреть файлы, они тоже не видны.Как почистить этот раздел "Прочее"?

P.S. Важно отметить, что в сам раздел прочее перейти нельзя

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С таким вопросом лучше на 4PDA, здесь больше про разработку.

Comment: если честно уже искал там, однако там огромное количество мусора и спама

Comment: Статья на эту тему: https://ichudoru.com/kak-ochistit-prochie-fayly-na-androide/

Comment: Тут рядом есть сообщество про андроид (Android entusiastas), там есть полезные вопросы по этой теме.

Comment: прочее это обычно данные программ (в мобильных ОС у каждой программы своя "папка Мои документы"), например видео в whatsapp, удаляются либо с помощью этих программ, либо удалением (переустановкой) самой программы

Comment: @PavelGridin все картинки и видео ватсапа можно удалить любым файловым менеджером или из галереи.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй storage analyser он должен это увидеть.[image: это я нашел на форуме]